# Converting number to floating point without making it a string

Tags: javascript

In this problem I'm working on, part of it is to return the returned value of a division problem, into a decimal number with 6 decimals. So I"m given 0.4, I have to return it has 0.400000, as a number, not a string. I've tried .toFixed(6) to give it the decimals, makes it a string, so then I try using parseFloat() to bring it back to a number, but it removes all the decimal places I added.

```
// Example

let num = 2 / 5
let floated = num.toFixed(6)
let final = parseFloat(num)
console.log(final)
```

Comment: Not possible. Use a string instead if you need trailing zeros

Comment: Its a HackerRank problem, and I'm getting it wrong because its returning strings haha. I have no clue how to get around this

Comment: Can you post a link to it? I'll check it out

Comment: But `0.4 === 0.400000`  So returning either as a number is the same thing.